# after clearing the neo4j database,when creating new node it starts to count from where the increment was before

Tags: neo4j

when I reset my neo4j database so that I get node(0) and new node IDs
start counting from 1.I've tried the neo4j-clean-remote-db-addonhttps://github.com/jexp/neo4j-clean-remote-db-addon and usng:

http://localhost:7474/db/data/cleandb/secret-key>

but although it returns a response of "Node[0]" it doesn't seem to do what
I need.  when I create a new node it starts counting from where
the increment was before. When I do:

I'm using v1.8 of both Neo4j and the plugin.How do I reset the node increment back to 1?, so that when i create new node it starts with id 1

Comment: Please edit your question to make sense. Read the faq on how to edit your question when it comes to links etc.

Comment: You have no control over the node ID of new nodes, and you should never depend on neo4j's generated node IDs to be consistent. They are meant for internal use only. Instead you should create your own unique identifier and find your nodes based on that.